# Add new column in Dataframe based on value in the array from another column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframework where one of column is a array. I am trying to get value from some elements in the array in this column and append this value as a new column

Here is the dataframe:

```
     Key    Version
0    ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]
1    ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]
2    ABC-3  [{'name': 'v3', 'releaseDate': '2023-03-01'}]
```

Here is my code:

```
df["NewColumn"] = df["Version"][0][0]['name']
```

The result is like below. It always pull the 1st value in row in the dataframe.

```
     Key    Version                                         NewColumn
0    ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]   v1
1    ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]   v1
2    ABC-3  [{'name': 'v3', 'releaseDate': '2023-03-01'}]   v1
```

I tried to use dataframe apply with lambda and it did not work. It says "KeyError: 0"

```
df["NewColumn"] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Version[0][0]['name'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to access specific elements within the array in the "Version" column and append the corresponding values as a new column. However, the code you provided is encountering issues because you're trying to access the first element in each row without considering the index. Additionally, using apply with lambda can be an appropriate approach in this case.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Creating a DataFrame
data = {
    "Key": ["ABC-1", "ABC-2", "ABC-3"],
    "Version": [[{"name": "v1", "releaseDate": "2023-01-01"}],
                [{"name": "v2", "releaseDate": "2023-02-01"}],
                []]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#      Key                                        Version
# 0  ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]
# 1  ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]
# 2  ABC-3                                             []


# Adding the new column named "NewColumn" to the DataFrame
df["NewColumn"] = df["Version"].apply(lambda x: x[0]["name"] if x else None)
print(df)
#      Key                                        Version NewColumn
# 0  ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]        v1
# 1  ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]        v2
# 2  ABC-3                                             []      None
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked but I found another issue. 
I noticed that in my dataset, there are rows where the Version column has no value in array, such as [], in those cases, the code is error out as "IndexError: list index out of range". Is there a good way to handle this exception so it does not error out? Thanks.

Comment: Code in the answer is updated. ABC-3 without Version items

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`.str[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html#pandas.Series.str.get) accessor to do that. With `df` your dataframe this

```py
df["NewColumn"] = df["Version"].str[0].str["name"]
```

yields

```
     Key                                        Version NewColumn
0  ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]        v1
1  ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]        v2
2  ABC-3  [{'name': 'v3', 'releaseDate': '2023-03-01'}]        v3
3  ABC-4                                             []       NaN
4  ABC-5                                            NaN       NaN
```

for the sample dataframe

```
     Key                                        Version
0  ABC-1  [{'name': 'v1', 'releaseDate': '2023-01-01'}]
1  ABC-2  [{'name': 'v2', 'releaseDate': '2023-02-01'}]
2  ABC-3  [{'name': 'v3', 'releaseDate': '2023-03-01'}]
3  ABC-4                                             []
4  ABC-5                                            NaN
```